# How to prove a function $f :R^2 \rightarrow R^2$ is differentiable?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

I want to prove a function   $f :R^2 \rightarrow R^2$ is differentiable in general. Is it sufficient to prove that the four partial derivatives exist at every point in $R^2$? In a text book I found the definition for differentiability.

$\lim_{h\rightarrow0} \frac{||f(x+h)-f(x)-T(h)||}{||h||} =0$ , where $T:R^2\rightarrow R^2, x \,\in R^2 $

But how does one find such a suitable $T(x)$?

Comment: If it exists, it must be the Jacobian. So the only one you need to try is the Jacobian.

Comment: The existance of partial derivatives is not enough. It is true if they are continuous, but not in general. Your definition is correct, and the way to find $T$ actually is through partial derivatives: $T$ has to be [Jacobian matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant#Jacobian_matrix), if it exists.

Comment: You can check each scalar (vector field) function $\;f_i: \Bbb R^2\to\Bbb R\;$ of your vector field. If its first partial derivatives exist and are continuous then it is a differentiable scalar function, and the vector field is differentiable iff each compnent is. Nevertheless in this case, as already commented above, it may be easier to check the Jacobian.

Comment: In short, existence of the partials does not guarantee differentiability. But continuous partials, denoted $f\in C^1$ is sufficient (but not necessary) for differentiability. This is usually good enough for most cases. For more pathological cases, as Vercassivelaunos said, you must check the Jacobian satisfies the limit definition. A good strategy here is to use different norms, especially the $l_{\infty}$ norm (all norms are equivalent in finite dimensional spaces).

Comment: Just to point out the obvious, which I am good at, when you evaluate the partials at $x$, it tells you nothing about how $f$ behaves 'off the axis lines through $x$'. Hence some stronger condition is needed.